# Running fast function and slow function with multi-threading in matlab

Tags: multithreading, matlab

I'm new with multi-threading in Matlab so I guess that what I need to do will be simple for anyone with a little experience in it.

I have two functions f1 and f2 such that:

f1 - runs about 10 seconds and returns accurate results.

f2 - return estimated results immediately.

Both functions get the same input and return the same output (but in f1 the output is more accurate).

The functions get new inputs all the time and run constantly.
I want to run the functions in two different threads so that the user will never need to wait.
and every time one of them finishes, the other one uses its results.

The goal is to get more accurate results than running f2 all the time. Running f1 all the time is the optimal solution but then the user needs to wait 10 seconds each time. So I want to combine the two functions and to get something in the middle.

What is the best way to implement the above?

I read about batch but I'm not sure it's what I need (at least I didn't find how to do the above with batch).

Can you just lead me with the relevant functions and I'll read about them and learn how to use them?

Thanks

Comment: For parallel computation you need to use the [Parallel Computing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing.html). Read the documentation to learn how.

Comment: One question: is `f1` more accurate than `f2` or more precise? (I hope it's the latter, otherwise `f2` is useless).

Comment: @CrisLuengo I know about Parallel Computing Toolbox. that's where I read about batch. I meant more specific functions. I'm not sure what's the difference between accurate and precise. I think that I actually meant precise. f1 and f2 are both accurate functions and implement completely different algorithms. The output that f1 returns is more accurate than the output that f2 returns.